# Find account from API or List ID

Tags: mailchimp

Here's an odd question...

I have multiple clients for whom I manage MC accounts, and I need to find out which account is associated with a particular API key and List ID. Is there any way of doing this? I have the List ID and API key, but cannot figure out which account the signups are going to!

Answer (score 0):

If you hit the [root of MailChip API v3](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/root/), you'll get the account username as a part of the response. You can use their [API Playground](https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/playground/) to make that call if you're not a developer.